# I’m everywhere with each passing second

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I'm pretty sure this one may be difficult.

> I am the ruler of the clouds in the sky.
>
> The cause of their fall, when the clouds cry.
>
> I am the forces of many things unseen,
>
> Two people have a tiff, and I’m in between.
>
> The real reason for almost everything you do.
>
> The imaginary eyes of people staring at you.
>
> I am a force with which to be reckoned.
>
> I’m everywhere with each passing second.

What am I?

Comment: "I'm pretty sure this one may be difficult" is part of puzzle?

Comment: has this been sandboxed?

Comment: @AditKirtani  sandbox is no longer mandatory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it

> Pressure?

I am the ruler of the clouds in the sky.

The cause of their fall, when the clouds cry.

> (Meteorologists, please don't be angry if this is wrong)
>  Rain and cloud forming is related to air pressure, right?

I am the forces of many things unseen,

> Correct air pressure "holds things together" here on earth, else we would implode or explode. Also, this has to do with "atomic pressure" I'd wager.

Two people have a tiff, and I’m in between.

> There can be fights, and that creates pressure

The real reason for almost everything you do.

> We wouldn't live our lives the way we did if we didn't have the pressure of surviving. In other words: Many people are in one way or another forced to do their daily lives a certain way, like finding a job - that's because of the "pressure" of expectations.

The imaginary eyes of people staring at you.

> You can feel pressured and uncomfortable by feeling watched

I am a force with which to be reckoned.

> Pressure can be deadly in many meanings of the word. Physical pressure, air pressure, emotional pressure...

I’m everywhere with each passing second.

> This could be about emotional and/or air pressure - emotional pressure is on everybody at least a tiny bit at any given time. Air pressure is always there on Earth.

Answer (score 0):

It may be

> gravity

Although I am not totally convinced by all my explanations and will continue to think, here they are:

I'm pretty sure this one may be difficult.

> Maybe linked to the saying 'to defy gravity' i.e. something is difficult

I am the ruler of the clouds in the sky.

> gravity controls the clouds by balancing the upward force and pulling water vapour together

The cause of their fall, when the clouds cry.

> gravity causes water moisture to fall when it gets too heavy

I am the forces of many things unseen,

> everything, even unseen things, enact a force of gravity

Two people have a tiff, and I’m in between.

> Gravity acts between any two objects (or in this case people)

The real reason for almost everything you do.

> the 'gravity of the situation' means the importantness of it; could be the cause of everything you do

The imaginary eyes of people staring at you.

> really not sure about this one

I am a force with which to be reckoned.

> gravity has the power to control planets; galaxies and everything in our universe

I’m everywhere with each passing second.

> gravity is always acting; no matter how far from an object you are

Comment: This one was my first idea but i donot post it.

Comment: @numberknot I'm not totally sold on it. I can't get the imaginary eyes one and the real reason explanation seems a bit iffy. Thought I'd post it anyway just in case!

Comment: @rsp If this is the intended answer then I think the question is wrong. "The real reason for almost everything you do"? If you must put that down to one physical force, I think it has to be the electromagnetic force (or the electroweak force, if you want to be fancy about it) rather than gravity. "The imaginary eyes of people staying at you"??

Answer (score 0):

My shot:

> Temperature / Heat

I am the ruler of the clouds in the sky.

The cause of their fall, when the clouds cry.

> When warm air rises, it expands and cools. Cool air can't hold as much water vapor as warm air, so some of the vapor condenses onto tiny pieces of dust that are floating in the air and forms a tiny droplet around each dust particle. When billions of these droplets come together they become a visible cloud.  Source: http://www.weatherwizkids.com/weather-clouds.htm

I am the forces of many things unseen,

> Everything has a temperature.

Two people have a tiff, and I’m in between.

> When 2 people have an argument (had to look "tiff" online) there is "heat" between them.

The real reason for almost everything you do.

> We do everything to get energy that (among others) heats our body.

The imaginary eyes of people staring at you.

> (I got nothing on this.)

I am a force with which to be reckoned.

> You don't want to mess with heat.

I’m everywhere with each passing second.

> Well...temperature/heat is everywhere. [If there wasn't  everything will stand still](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_zero)